# String Replace With Variable In Array

Tags: php, arrays, str-replace

Ok if I use the code:

```
$phrase  = "You should eat fruits, vegetables, and fiber every day.";
$healthy = array("fruits", "vegetables", "fiber");
$yummy   = array("pizza", "beer", "ice cream");
$newphrase = str_replace($healthy, $yummy, $phrase);

// Provides: You should eat pizza, beer, and ice cream every day
```

However what if my list of words to replace are a variable.

```
$sample1 = "fruits, vegetables, fiber";
$sample2 = "pizza, beer, ice cream";
$phrase  = "You should eat fruits, vegetables, and fiber every day.";
$healthy = array($sample1);
$yummy   = array($sample2);
$newphrase = str_replace($healthy, $yummy, $phrase);

// Provides: You should eat fruits, vegetables, and fiber every day.
```

Same if I use:

```
$sample1 = '"fruits", "vegetables", "fiber"';
$sample1 = '"pizza", "beer", "ice cream"';
$phrase  = "You should eat fruits, vegetables, and fiber every day.";
$healthy = array($sample1);
$yummy   = array($sample2);
$newphrase = str_replace($healthy, $yummy, $phrase);
```

Am I missing something?

Is there a way to do this easily?

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to turn the strings in to arrays, use explode in this case:

```
$sample1 = "fruits, vegetables, fiber";
$sample2 = "pizza, beer, ice cream";
$phrase  = "You should eat fruits, vegetables, and fiber every day.";
    $healthy = explode(',',$sample1);
    $yummy   = explode(',',$sample2);
$newphrase = str_replace($healthy, $yummy, $phrase);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can *explode* a `string` into an `array` using a separator:

```
$sample1 = "fruits, vegetables, fiber";
$sample2 = "pizza, beer, ice cream";
$phrase  = "You should eat fruits, vegetables, and fiber every day.";
$healthy = explode(",", $sample1);
$yummy   = explode(",", $sample2);
$newphrase = str_replace($healthy, $yummy, $phrase);
```

I would recommend that you don't have white space between each string though. If you're going to do that then you'll probably want to `trim()` each value. `array_map()` comes in useful here because you can map a function to every value like this:

```
$healthy = array_map('trim', explode(",", $sample1));
```

So the whole thing would be more like:

```
$sample1 = "fruits    ,    vegetables,fiber";
$sample2 = "pizza,      beer,ice cream";
$phrase  = "You should eat fruits, vegetables, and fiber every day.";
$healthy = array_map('trim', explode(",", $sample1));
$yummy   = array_map('trim', explode(",", $sample2));
$newphrase = str_replace($healthy, $yummy, $phrase);
```